# VBA Word macro to stop user input

Tags: vba, input, ms-word

I'm writing a big macro for MS Word 2013 and one of the parts of it should be sub that prevents user from writing text; user should be able to use hotkey (eg. ctrl+q) to stop (or start) this sub (I already know how to assign a hotkey to a sub). I'm pretty new to VBA. I've googled for the answer but there's only instruction how to write such macro for Excel, but it doesn't work in Word. Is there a way to do this? How? 
Thank you in advance.

```
Dim startTime As Single
Dim stopTime As Single
Dim timeToRun
Dim totalTime
Dim tmpTime
Dim avg As Long
Public isStart As Boolean

Public Sub hotkeyPressed() 'I wrote module to handle this'
If isStart = True Then
stopButton_Click
Else
startButton_Click
End If
End Sub

Private Sub startButton_Click()
totalTime = tmpTime
startTime = Timer
isStart = True
startButton.Enabled = False
stopButton.Enabled = True
ActiveDocument.Protect _
Type:=wdNoProtection
End Sub

Private Sub stopButton_Click()
isStart = False
stopTime = Timer
tmpTime = totalTime + tmpTime
startButton.Enabled = True
stopButton.Enabled = False
ActiveDocument.Protect _
Type:=wdAllowOnlyReading
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()
startButton.Caption = "Start!"
stopButton.Caption = "Stop"
isStart = False
Call scheduler
ActiveDocument.Protect _
Type:=wdAllowOnlyReading
On Error GoTo Handler:
Open "KM\" + ActiveDocument.Name + ".txt" For Input As #1
Input #1, line
tmpTime = line
Close #1
Exit Sub
Handler:
tmpTime = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Close()
MyFile1 = "KM\" + ActiveDocument.Name + ".txt"
fnum = FreeFile()
Open MyFile1 For Output As fnum
Print #fnum, totalTime
Close fnum
End Sub

Private Sub scheduler()
timeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime timeToRun, "getNumberOfLetters"
End Sub

Sub getNumberOfLetters()
If isStart = True Then
numOfLetters = ActiveDocument.Characters.Count
totalTime = Timer - startTime
timeLabel.Caption = totalTime + tmpTime
charLabel.Caption = numOfLetters
setResult
End If
Call scheduler
End Sub

Private Sub setResult()
avg = 60 * numOfLetters / czasLabel.Caption
avg.Caption = avg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply using the `.Protect` method?

```
Sub ProtectDocument()

ActiveDocument.Protect _
    Type:=wdAllowOnlyReading

End Sub
```

This will prevent user input. You can unprotect the document using VBA if necessary:

```
Sub UnprotectDocument()

ActiveDocument.Protect _
    Type:=wdNoProtection

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work the way I want it to. It doesn't allow me to simply turn the protection off - when I try to call UnprotectDocument I get en error "The Protect Method or property is not available because this document is locked for editing".

Comment: Well then something else you are doing is interfering.  Unless you're willing to post your code and/or a version of your DOCX it's not possible for me to troubleshoot for you.

Comment: On stop we shouldn't be allowed to write anything; on start protection should be taken off. I made it in ugly way - by adding modal Message Dialog. This program should every second count the number of characters and total time of writing - and give an average char/minute.